# If a Class Within a Div is Not Found, Insert a Div Before?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, performance, function

I am wanting to display a div `.before()` another if it does **not** contain a specific class within it. Though it seems simple enough, somehow I am not able to get it working...

Here's a snippet of the progress I've made so far:

```js
$('.container > #content').not('.entry', function() {
  $(this).before('<div class="noentry">No entries to display.</div>');
});
```

```css
body {
  font-size: 16px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 22px;
  margin-top: 0;
}

.container {
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 300px;
  border: 1px solid lightgrey;
  padding: 10px;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <h1>Section With an Entry:</h1>
  <div id="content">
    <div class="entry">This is an entry.</div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <h1>Section Without an Entry:</h1>
  <div id="content"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: IDs **must** be unique

Comment: Why not use CSS? `.content:empty { content: “no entries to display”; }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`.not()`](http://api.jquery.com/not/) method does not work as you are expecting. It only checks the immediate object for the `.entry` class. You need to search descendants. See the updated example below, you can use a [`.find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/).

Also, as noted in the comments above, you shouldn't duplicate ids, so I changed your `content` to a class.

```js
$(function() {
  $('.container > .content').each(function() {
    if (!$(this).find(".entry").length) {
      $(this).before('<div class="noentry">No entries to display.</div>');
    }
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  font-size: 16px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 22px;
  margin-top: 0;
}

.container {
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 300px;
  border: 1px solid lightgrey;
  padding: 10px;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <h1>Section With an Entry:</h1>
  <div class="content">
    <div class="entry">This is an entry.</div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <h1>Section Without an Entry:</h1>
  <div class="content"></div>
</div>
```